# C# - Trying to create a "selected" state for several buttons

Tags: c#

What I want to do is creating a menu with several buttons and when the user clicks on one of them, the selected button tag gets stored in a variable and the background color of that button gets highlighted. When the user clicks another button, the previous stored variable gets compared with the new variable and if it is different, it changes the background color of the earlier pressed button back to normal. This is what I have so far:

```
   if (!isSelected)
   {
       b.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(28, 145, 162);
       previousPress = (int)b.Tag;
       isSelected = true;

       if(previousPress != currentPress)
       {
        b(previousPress).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(12, 34, 567); // Obviously this wont work, but hopefully it clears up on what I want to reach.
        isSelected = false;
        currentPress = (int)b.Tag;


        }

   }
```

The .Tag idea of B is ranging from 1 till 7, as that is how many buttons are created in the constructor method.

---

That is what I tried to use, but someone suggested I shouldn't be using tags for this, as it should only cause bugs and errors. He suggested the following:

```
Button previousButton = b;

if (previousButton != currentButton)
    ...
```

I understand the logic behind this, but sadly before he went away before I could ask where and how the currentButton variable is declared/used. Could someone shine some light upon this? Thank you!

Comment: You'd declare it as a field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that all the buttons are assigned the same `Click` event, this code would do exactly what you want:

```
    Color _activeColor = Color.Red;
    private void buttons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Button btn in this.Controls.OfType<Button>()
                    .Where(b => b.BackColor == _activeColor))
        {
            btn.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        }
        ((Button)sender).BackColor = _activeColor;
    }
```

It clears out the button who previously had `_activeColor` and sets the color to the current one.

This is pretty common approach to what (I believe) you need. Try to understand this code before trying it, it's relying on [Linq](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33769/Basics-of-LINQ-Lamda-Expressions).

Comment: Though I like it, i think the OP might have enough with a simple switch as well, not like it would be that much extra work to show :)